# delay() block its coroutine when using thread pool as the dispatcher?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Play with Kotlin coroutine, I am confused by the results of my toy code:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

suspend fun task(sleepTime: Long) {
    println("start task in Thread ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    delay(sleepTime)
    //yield()
    println("end task with context in Thread ${Thread.currentThread()}")
}

println("start")
runBlocking {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler() { context, ex ->
        println("Caught: $context | ${ex.message}")
    }
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
        .asCoroutineDispatcher().use { dispatcher ->
            launch(dispatcher + handler) { task(100) }
            launch(Dispatchers.IO + handler) { task(1000) }
            println("called tasks ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        }
}
println("done")
```

output:

```
start
start task in Thread Thread[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2,5,main]
called tasks Thread[main @coroutine#1,5,main]
start task in Thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#3,5,main]
end task with context in Thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 @coroutine#3,5,main]
done
```

My question is why coroutine#1 does not continue? If I change delay() to yield(), it worked:

```
start
start task in Thread Thread[pool-1-thread-1 @coroutine#2,5,main]
end task with context in Thread Thread[pool-1-thread-2 @coroutine#2,5,main]
called tasks Thread[main @coroutine#1,5,main]
start task in Thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#3,5,main]
end task with context in Thread Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#3,5,main]
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Closeable.use` executes the code inside it and then closes the Closable, in this case your dispatcher. Since launched coroutines are run asynchronously, `use` doesn't wait for them to finish, and shuts down the dispatcher right away, thereby cancelling your coroutines. It's possible `yield()` happens so quickly that they have time to finish before getting cancelled.

If you move your `use` block outside the `runBlocking` block, then it waits for them to finish.

```
fun main() {
    println("start")
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)
        .asCoroutineDispatcher().use { dispatcher ->
            runBlocking {
                val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler() { context, ex ->
                    println("Caught: $context | ${ex.message}")
                }
                launch(dispatcher + handler) { task(100) }
                launch(Dispatchers.IO + handler) { task(1000) }
                println("called tasks ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            }
        }
    println("done")
}
```

Comment: Outside of toy-examples, the strategy of moving the `runBlocking` cannot apply. The more general way is to wrap the `launch`es with `coroutineScope {`, which waits for the children in the scope to complete before returning.

Comment: The only place `runBlocking` should ever appear in an app is directly in the `main` function. But that's a good point. I think the reason it is so misused is that the documentation uses it in all their simplified examples.

Comment: my problem was I didn't realize that the use{} close the resource. thanks @Tenfour04! Also, I agree with @GeorgeLeung that use coroutineScope is a better choice in general.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to spot this problem during debugging. I am not able to think out a place to put a breakpoint to show the problem in my original code in the IDEs (Intellij)

Comment: It's tricky to find a problem with asynchronous/multithreaded code by using breakpoints. It break on one thread while the others continue executing and thereby change the behavior.